# Based on geometry, Triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

What is the least possible length of a line segment that cuts a triangle with sides 3,4,5 in to two geometric figures having equal area?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why don't you answer to @Dr. Mthva 5 hours after the question has been asked, immediately after you posted yours ? This site is for exchanges with askers that have really worked on their subject.

Comment: HINT: 3,4,5 is a pythogorean triplet. So it is a right angled triangle

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Among triangles of equal area with a given angle between two sides, the isosceles triangle has the least possible side opposite to the angle.
2. Among isosceles triangles of equal area, the triangle with the smallest angle has the least possible side opposite to the angle.

Applying the above considerations and some simple trigonometry you should end up with the answer "2".

Comment: Did you mean isosceles triangles?

Comment: @DanielMathias Of course. Thank you for catching this.

Comment: Can i get proof of HINT #1.

Comment: It is geometrically obvious but you can get it also algebraically minimizing $a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\alpha$ subject to constrain $ab\sin\alpha=2A$.

Comment: I know this is obvious but i need to proof algebraically. Sorry to say, thing you wrote i didnt get that. Please help me in this.

Comment: @KeshavKumar Can you compute derivatives of simple (power) functions?

Comment: not more about it

Comment: I proved it, thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @KeshavKumar You are welcome.